# "Object Required" when calling function in sub in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, function, vba, object, required

In my VBA program for excel; I have a function called "ParamCheck" which get four "double" variables, checks them and returns a message as "string".

```
Function ParamCheck(airSpeed As Double, FCUvalue As Double, _
            altitude As Double, terrainElevation As Double) As String

            If airSpeed < MIN_CONTROL_SPEED Then                            
            'check if airspeed is less than 119 ft/min or not
                ParamCheck = "Airspeed is less than minimum control speed"

            ElseIf FCUvalue > FCU_VALUE_LIMIT Then                          
            'check if FCU value if greater than 10 or not
                ParamCheck = "FCU value is greater than limit"

            ElseIf FCUvalue < 0 Then                                        
            'check if FCU vlaue is negative or not
                ParamCheck = "FCU value is negative"

            ElseIf altitude <= terrainElevation Then                        
            'check if altitude is greater that terrain of elevation or not
                ParamCheck = "Altitude is less than terrain elevation"

            Else                                                            
            'if all the parameters are valid print a "Valid" message
                ParamCheck = PARAMS_OK
            End If
End Function
```

and now I need to call this function in my sub program. Here is the code

```
Dim checkParam As String    ' result of validity check of parameters
Set checkParam = ParamCheck(speedAir, valueFCU, aboveSea, elevationTerrain)
```

when running it gives me this error "object required" and highlights "checkParam"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the keyword `Set` for the type String, that's why.

Unlike to other programming languages, VBA considers **String** as a *Data Type*, and not as an *Object*.

The keyword `Set` is used to assign a reference to an object (Worksheet, Range, etc...).

If you try to assign a reference to a data type, as you did, you will get an error.